# ElasticSearch Nest Repository Sample

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Should I use nest library or is it better to talk elasticsearh over via rest api.

Can anyone share c# repository sample with use nest library and also nest query samples with c#.

Answer (score 0):

Define what you mean by better :) NEST uses the REST API but also adds a bunch of really useful features such as

- Strongly typed requests and responses
- A Fluent lambda API and an Object Initializer syntax (API)
- Inference of index names, type names, document ids from POCOs
- Covariant search results
- Automapping of POCOs from property types, attributed properties and a fluent API
- Knowledge of valid responses for each endpoint e.g. `404`s for Exists responses
- Cluster failover connection pooling with ability to self-update based on cluster state
- Operator overloading for combining queries in both query and filter context
- Conditionless, strict and verbatim semantics when building compound queries

You can implement all or a subset of this yourself if you need/want to, and if you do, we'd love to know why to see if there is something in NEST that can be improved.

There is also [Elasticsearch.Net](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/elasticsearch-net.html), the official low level .NET client for Elasticsearch, that is much less opinionated than NEST, the official high level client. Internally, NEST uses the low level client and still exposes it via the `.LowLevel` property. It'd be worth taking a look at that as well, to see if it better suits your needs.

[For examples, take a look at the Nusearch repository.](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example)